# Filtering Data with Box in Shiny before converted to table

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app currently has preset tables that are loaded in using DT and simply published. These tables are grouped/summarised from a larger dataset with more vars, but I want to add a box in shiny to filter the large dataset first, by say a random var (0,1) and take the groupby/summarise from there.

```
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 
5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5, 5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, 5.2, 
5.5, 4.9, 5, 5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5, 4.5, 4.4, 5, 5.1, 4.8, 5.1, 
4.6, 5.3, 5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 
5, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 5.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, 6.3, 
6.1, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.7, 6, 5.7, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 6, 5.4, 6, 6.7, 
6.3, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.7, 6.2, 5.1, 5.7, 
6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6.8, 
5.7, 5.8, 6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6, 6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 
6.2, 6.1, 6.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.9, 6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, 6.4, 6, 
6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 5.8, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 
4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 
2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 
2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 
2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 
3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 
3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 
2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 
3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 
3), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 
1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 
1.5, 1, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 
1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.6, 
1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.7, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, 
3.5, 4.2, 4, 4.7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.5, 4.1, 4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4, 4.9, 
4.7, 4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.7, 4.4, 4.1, 4, 4.4, 4.6, 4, 3.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3, 4.1, 
6, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, 5.8, 6.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 
5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 6.7, 6.9, 5, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 5.7, 6, 4.8, 
4.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.1, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.6, 5.5, 4.8, 5.4, 
5.6, 5.1, 5.1, 5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1, 1.3, 1.4, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 
1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 
1.1, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 
1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 
1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 
1.5, 2.3, 2, 2, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 
1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 
1.9, 2, 2.3, 1.8), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor"), 
    x = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-150L), class = "data.frame")
```

Take this DF for example. I want to have a button for the x variable, and have my output be a dataframe of Sepal Length, Width, Petal Length and Width for each species if x is 1 or 0.
And I want to be able to do this to multiple different cols

Answer (score 0):

Lots of info for you at https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

```
df <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
                                      5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 
                                      5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5, 5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4, 5.2, 
                                      5.5, 4.9, 5, 5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5, 4.5, 4.4, 5, 5.1, 4.8, 5.1, 
                                      4.6, 5.3, 5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 
                                      5, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 5.6, 6.7, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, 6.3, 
                                      6.1, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.7, 6, 5.7, 5.5, 5.5, 5.8, 6, 5.4, 6, 6.7, 
                                      6.3, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.7, 6.2, 5.1, 5.7, 
                                      6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6.8, 
                                      5.7, 5.8, 6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6, 6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 
                                      6.2, 6.1, 6.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.9, 6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, 6.4, 6, 
                                      6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 5.8, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9), 
                     Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
                                     3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 
                                     4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
                                     3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 
                                     2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 
                                     2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3, 2.7, 
                                     2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 
                                     2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 
                                     3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 
                                     3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 
                                     2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 
                                     3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 
                                     3),
                     Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 
                                      1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 
                                      1.5, 1, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 
                                      1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.6, 
                                      1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.7, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, 
                                      3.5, 4.2, 4, 4.7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.5, 4.1, 4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4, 4.9, 
                                      4.7, 4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 
                                      4.7, 4.4, 4.1, 4, 4.4, 4.6, 4, 3.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3, 4.1, 
                                      6, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, 5.8, 6.1, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 
                                      5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 6.7, 6.9, 5, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 5.7, 6, 4.8, 
                                      4.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.1, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.6, 5.5, 4.8, 5.4, 
                                      5.6, 5.1, 5.1, 5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1), 
                     Petal.Width = c(0.2, 
                                     0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 
                                     0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
                                     0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 
                                     0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 
                                     1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1, 1.3, 1.4, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 
                                     1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 
                                     1.1, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 
                                     1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 
                                     1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 
                                     1.5, 2.3, 2, 2, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 
                                     1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 
                                     1.9, 2, 2.3, 1.8), 
                     Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                           3L), 
                                         .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor"), 
                     x = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
                           1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
                           1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                           0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                           1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                           0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
                           1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
                           1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), 
                row.names = c(NA, 
                              -150L), 
                class = "data.frame")


library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("My title"),
  
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      #There are lots of button options in the Shiny Cheat Sheet or other sources
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'myButton', 
                    label = 'Select x', 
                    choices = unique(df$x), 
                    selected = unique(df$x)
                    ),
      # Output: table ----
      DTOutput(outputId = "myTable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$myTable <- renderDT({
    
    xFilter <- input$myButton
    
    filteredDf <- df %>% 
      
      filter(x == xFilter)
    
    datatable(filteredDf, 
              rownames = F,
              options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(5)))))
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```